# Parse the incoming packet

Tags: c, arduino

I am receiving a packet like 0xFA5D0D01.
Now i want to parce it like

FA is Header1 
5D is Header2 
0D is length and 
01 is checksum.
const int data_availabe = Serial.available();

I am able to write to serial port but not able to parce it like 
if i received FA is then print received Header1

```
const int data_availabe = Serial.available();
if (data_availabe <= 0) 
{
    return;
}
const int c = Serial.read();

Serial.print("Receive Status: ");
Serial.println(STATE_NAME[receiveState]);
Serial.print(c, HEX);
Serial.print(" ");
if (isprint(c))          //isprint checks whether it is printable character or not (e.g non printable char = \t)
{
  Serial.write(c);
} 
Serial.println();   
Serial.println(receiveState);   

switch (receiveState)
{
case WAITING_FOR_HEADER1:
    if (c == HEADER1)
    {
        receiveState = WAITING_FOR_HEADER2;

    }
    break;

case WAITING_FOR_HEADER2:
    if (c == HEADER2)
    {
        receiveState = WAITING_FOR_LENGTH;
    }
    break;
}
```

Where receiveState is enum changing as we are getting exptected data..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the Arduino is receiving data from USB.

What is the `if (data available <= 0)` doing? If you want want to read data from the serial port while it is avalaible, you should better do `if (Serial.avalaible() > 1)` and then `Serial.read()` inside the `{}`.

If you initialize a `const` you won't be able to change its value over time...

What is `readString` and how is it initialized?

Have you tried to `Serial.print(c)` to see what's inside?

Once again, it would be easier for us if you could give us more context on why and when this piece of code is running.

**EDIT**:

```
#define HEADER_1 0xFA // here you define your headers, etc. You can also use variables.

uint8_t readByte[4]; // your packet is 4 bytes long. each byte is stored in this array.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    while (Serial.avalaible() > 1) { // when there is data avalaible on the serial port

        readByte[0] = Serial.read(); // we store the first incomming byte.
        delay(10);

        if (readByte[0] == HEADER_1) { // and check if that byte is equal to HEADER_1

            for (uint8_t i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++) { // if so we store the 3 last bytes into the array
                readByte[i] = Serial.read();
                delay(10);
            }

        }

    }

    //then you can do what you want with readByte[]... i.e. check if readByte[1] is equal  to HEADER_2 and so on :)

}
```

Comment: This is not in regards to USB, this serial is rs-232, if you don't know the answer then don't answer.

Comment: please see the updated question...i am not able to parse it as expected..something goes wrong somewhere...

Comment: @ChrisDesjardins I might me totally stupid, but how do you know that?
I edited my answer, tell me if it's what you want to do.

Comment: Indeed, much better, but I still don't know why you "assume the Arduino is receiving data from USB"

Comment: I meant that, in my theoritical representation of the project, the Arduino was connected to the computer USB port "as usual", not bluetooth (though similar), not Ethernet or Wifi.